# How to install QGIS using Conda on Mac

Tags: macos, anaconda, qgis

I tried to install qgis 2.18 on MacOS Sierra using

> conda install -c conda-forge qgis

As given at l[ink](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis) and getting an error:

> PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
>     - qgis

Suggest how to handle and install it

Comment: Have you tried this from qgis site: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: The issue with  kyngchaos.com is that the software uses predefined location for assessing the python and R packages. hence does not work with third party installed packages on Mac